# mysql SELECT IN followed by comma separated field

Tags: mysql, list, nested

I use mySQL and I have a members table with a BLOB 'contacts' field containing a comma separated list of other member's IDs:

```
TABLE members:
id_member = 1
firstname = 'John'
contacts (BLOB) = '4,6,7,2,5'
```

I want to retrieve all the first names in the 'contacts' list of an individual, with a single query. I tried the following:

```
SELECT firstname from members WHERE id_member IN ( SELECT contacts FROM members WHERE id_member = 1 );
```

It returns only one row, but when I try:

```
SELECT firstname from members WHERE id_member IN ( 4,6,7,2,5 );
```

It returns all the first names from the list. I can use two queries to achieve this, but I thought I'd double check if there's a way to make it work with one simple, elegant query.

Thanks for reading, any help appreciated.
Jul

Comment: Is your ID numeric and your blob a string?

Comment: The solution here is to properly normalize the database with a contacts table having two columns: `id_member` and `id_contact`, for which there are many rows per `id_member`.

Comment: Yes, Jrod, my ID is INT and blob is a string. Thanks for the idea Michael, but I have a reserve for this option that I expressed in my comment to Tadman's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change this DB structure? The contacts field really should be a related table rather than a column. Assuming a contacts table with this structure:

```
id_contact
id_member
```

Then you would use EXISTS instead:

```
SELECT firstname from members m WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contacts c WHERE c.id_contact = m.id_member );
```

Comment: That's a good looking query. I'm going for a related table, thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

That seems like a very poor table design. Is it possible to change it?

If you can't change the design then you can handle comma separated values in MySQL by using [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) but it won't be able to use indexes efficiently:

```
SELECT firstname
FROM members
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_member, (SELECT contacts FROM members WHERE id_member = 1))
```

But rather than going this route, I'd *strongly* recommend that if possible you [normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Consider using a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) instead of a comma separated list. Then you can find the entries you need by using joins and the search will be able to use an index.

Comment: I didn't know about `FIND_IN_SET` but I bet that's going to be brutally slow on large data-sets since it results in an automatic table scan and can't be indexed. Neat trick, though.

Comment: Thanks for the research links, very helpful. I'm going for a normalized db

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a serialized `BLOB` type column to store these values then you're not going to be able to do what you want. A more SQL friendly approach is to create a relationship table that can be used as part of a `JOIN` operation, such as a `member_contacts` table that has an association between one `id_member` value and some other.

Expanding your comma separated list into individual records is a pretty simple mechanical process.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. I considered this approach but the idea that gathering the contact list of a single member requires to browse a table filled with everyone's contact entries seemed inefficient. I'll definitely go for if it's faster

Comment: If you index this on the `id_member` you're using in your `WHERE` clause, this is actually very fast even on large sets of data. Always have indexes for any frequent queries.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just that